# Is there a way to find Orthodox Jewish lawyers or majority Jewish law firms?

Tags: parnassah-livelihood

I hope this question is on topic, as I am asking about lawyers and law firms that specifically are run by Orthodox Jewish men and women.

I am currently a New York law school student and have a desire to work for, and work with, other shomer-shabbos Jews. I am curious if the Mi Yodeya community knows of a resource that may allow me to find these types of jobs?

Comment: Sorry this isn't about Judaism

Comment: I know there is some sort of organization in Los Angeles.